# Pass Binding to openwindow in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, binding, window

I have a SwiftUI program which has the basic structure of the following.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    
    @AppStorage("exponent") var exponent = 3
    @AppStorage("expList") var expList = [3]
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ResultView(exponent: Double(exponent))
                .id(exponent)
        }
        WindowGroup("Input Window", id: "inputWindow", for: Calculation.self) { $calc in
            InputView(calculation: $calc)
        } defaultValue: {
            return Calculation(exponent: Double(exponent))
        }
       .commands{
            CommandMenu("Tools"){
                Menu("Exponents"){
                    Picker("",selection: $exponent){
                        ForEach(expList, id:\.self) { exp in
                            Text(String(exp)).tag(exp)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.inline)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    Divider()
                    Button("Add"){
                        expList = expList.sorted()
                        let newExp = expList.last! + 1
                        expList.append(newExp)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    var exponent: Double
    @Published public var calculation: Calculation
    
    init(exponent: Double) {
        self.exponent = exponent
        self.calculation = Calculation(exponent: exponent)
    }
    
}
struct Calculation: Codable, Hashable {
    
    var exponent: Double
    var input: Double = 2
    var result: Double {
        return pow(input, exponent)
    }
    
    init(exponent: Double) {
        self.exponent = exponent
    }
}

struct ResultView: View {
    
    @StateObject var model: Model
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
    var exponent: Double
    
    init(exponent: Double) {
        self.exponent = exponent
        self._model = StateObject(wrappedValue: Model(exponent: exponent))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Set Input"){
                openWindow(id:"inputWindow", value: model.calculation)
            }
            Text("Exponent: \(exponent)")
            Text("Input: \(model.calculation.input)")
            Text("Result: \(model.calculation.result)")
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}

struct InputView: View {
    @Binding var calculation: Calculation
    
    init(calculation: Binding<Calculation>){
        self._calculation = calculation
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("Input: ")
            TextField("", value: $calculation.input, format: .number)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

extension Array: RawRepresentable where Element: Codable {
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
              let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = result
    }
    
    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "[]"
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

What I want is for the `InputView` window to allow for changes to the `input` and reflect the `result` in `ResultView`.   In my actual program, these views have much more data. The updating works correctly if I make `ResultView` a `.popover`, but I really need to be able to see both views simultaneously and allow them to be moved, which I cannot do with a `.popover`.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your code is confused and lacks all the generics. Please, provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. By the way maybe I'd use an environmentObject to solve this.

Comment: I updated with a working version of the code to be a minimal reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

As I already mentioned in the comment, you could have done it injecting the Observable Model into the views. This will automatically propagate changes in other view that have a subscription to that Publisher.

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    
    @AppStorage("exponent") var exponent = 3
    @AppStorage("expList") var expList = [3]
    
    @StateObject private var model: Model = Model(exponent: 3)
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ResultView(exponent: Double(exponent))
                .environmentObject(model)
                .id(exponent)
        }
        WindowGroup("Input Window", id: "inputWindow", for: Calculation.self) { $calc in
            InputView(calculation: $model.calculation)
                /// Inject it here too if necessary only
                //.environmentObject(model)
        }
       .commands{
            CommandMenu("Tools"){
                Menu("Exponents"){
                    Picker("",selection: $exponent){
                        ForEach(expList, id:\.self) { exp in
                            Text(String(exp)).tag(exp)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.inline)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    Divider()
                    Button("Add"){
                        expList = expList.sorted()
                        let newExp = expList.last! + 1
                        expList.append(newExp)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ResultView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
    var exponent: Double
    
    init(exponent: Double) {
        self.exponent = exponent
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Set Input"){
                openWindow(id:"inputWindow", value: model.calculation)
            }
            Text("Exponent: \(exponent)")
            Text("Input: \(model.calculation.input)")
            Text("Result: \(model.calculation.result)")
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}

struct InputView: View {
    
    @Binding var calculation: Calculation
    
    init(calculation: Binding<Calculation>){
        self._calculation = calculation
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("Input: ")
            TextField("", value: $calculation.input, format: .number)
                
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I injected the model into subviews using the `environmentObject` modifier and passing it the object. Then from a subview whose parent has an inject object of that type you can access it using `@EnvironmentObject` property wrapper.
By the way, your code did not work because there was no relation between the Model in the ResutView and the Calculation in the InputView. They were basically two different entities with no coummunication.
Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks. The problem here is that @StateObject is defined in MainApp and will not be updated if there is a change in `exponent`.  So I trade one issue for another. I went the route because it was the only way I understood @StateObject can be updated, per Apple Documentation on @StateObject.

Comment: Did you try using the onAppear and updating the exponent of the model there?

Comment: I tried using .onChange(of $exponent){}

Comment: I'll give it a look tomorrow. Now I'm not at home. But I meant something like this: ResultView(exponent: Double(exponent))
                .environmentObject(model)
                .id(exponent).onAppear {}

Comment: I tried that it did not work, because ResultView is still appearing.  In the Menu Picker, I did .onChange(of: exponent) {model.calculation.exponent = exponent}.   That only resets after I select the Menu Tools again. So halfway there.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe tomorrow I can look more into it. If my solution did help you I would appreciate if you could give my answer an upvote.

Comment: SOLVED -- I changed the Menu selection to be a Button whose action updated the model. And upvoted you.  Thanks again!